# Retrieve vimeo videos by category with API

Tags: php, api, categories, vimeo

Just trying to wrap my head around Vimeo API...
I have succeeded fetching a list of videos by a search query:

```
$limit = 10; // number of videos to display
$vimeo = new phpVimeo($key, $secret);
$response = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.search', array('per_page' => $limit, 'query' => $query, 'sort' => 'relevant'));
```

However, when I'm trying to do the same thing to get the list of videos by category, I get 500 - internal server error. What am I missing?

```
    $limit = 10; // number of videos to display for each search
    $vimeo = new phpVimeo($key, $secret);
    $response = $vimeo->call('vimeo.categories.getRelatedVideos', array('per_page' => 10, 'category' => $videocategory));
```

`$videocategory` is existing Vimeo category that works in playground.

`$key` is my key

`$secret` is empty string

Answer (score 0):

This is the old API. It has been deprecated for months. You should be using the new API: https://developer.vimeo.com and the new PHP library: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

You can learn about Vimeo's category API here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/categories